# How to get last part of http link in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, cut

I have an http link :

```
http://www.test.com/abc/def/efg/file.jar
```

and I want to save the last part file.jar to variable, so the output string is "file.jar".

**Condition**: link can has different length e.g.:

```
http://www.test.com/abc/def/file.jar.
```

I tried it that way:

```
awk -F'/' '{print $7}'
```

, but problem is the length of URL, so I need a command which can be used for any URL length.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Using `awk` for this would work, but it's kind of deer hunting with a howitzer.  If you already have your URL bare, it's pretty simple to do what you want if you put it into a shell variable and use `bash`'s built-in parameter substitution:

```
$ myurl='http://www.example.com/long/path/to/example/file.ext'
$ echo ${myurl##*/}
file.ext
```

The way this works is by removing a prefix that greedily matches '*/', which is what the `##` operator does:

```
${haystack##needle} # removes any matching 'needle' from the
                    # beginning of the variable 'haystack'
```

Comment: Any sort of explanation to go with that?

Comment: Sure.  Will that do?

Comment: That is great :)

Comment: If you want to strip query strings, you can first assign to an intermediate variable e.g. `file=${myurl##*/}`, then use greedy reverse-matching to back up to the `?` (don't forget to escape it!), e.g. `echo ${file%%\?*}`

Answer (score 33):

`basename` and `dirname` work good for URLs too:

```
> url="http://www.test.com/abc/def/efg/file.jar"
> basename "$url"; basename -s .jar "$url"; dirname "$url"
file.jar
file
http://www.test.com/abc/def/efg
```

Comment: +1 Brilliant, it works because an URL and a PATH and both URIs.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova a path isn't a [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier); this works because `basename` and `dirname` split strings on /, and that happens to work with URLs too, at least as long as they don't have a local portion (not with URIs in general though).

Comment: In the Wikipedia article about URIs, they give the following as valid examples of URI references: `/relative/URI/with/absolute/path/to/resource.txt`, `relative/path/to/resource.txt`, `../../../resource.txt` and `resource.txt`  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Examples_of_URI_references

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Wikipedia is not wrong, `/relative/path` can be either a file system path or a relative URI. But which of those it is depends on the context. When it's used as a file system path, it's not a URI. When it's used as a URI, it's not a file system path. Saying it's a URI just because it happens to match the syntax is like saying each of the words in this comment is a URI as well.

Answer (score 14):

With `awk`, you can use `$NF`, to get the last field, regardless of number of fields:

```
awk -F / '{print $NF}'
```

If you store that string in shell variable, you can use:

```
a=http://www.test.com/abc/def/efg/file.jar
printf '%s\n' "${a##*/}"
```

Answer (score 6):

Most of the posted answers are not robust on URLs that contain query strings or targets, such as, for example, the following:

https://example.com/this/is/a/path?query#target

Python has URL parsing in its standard library; it's easier to let it do it. E.g.,

```
from urllib import parse
import sys
path = parse.urlparse(sys.stdin.read().strip()).path
print("/" if not path or path == "/" else path.rsplit("/", 1)[-1])
```

You can compact that into a single `python3 -c` for use in a shell script:

```
echo 'https://example.com/this/is/a/path/componets?query#target' \
    | python3 -c 'from urllib import parse; import sys; path = parse.urlparse(sys.stdin.read().strip()).path; print("/" if not path or path == "/" else path.rsplit("/", 1)[-1])'
```

(You can also keep the script broken out, too, for readability. `'` will let you put newlines in.)

Of course, now your shell script has a dependency on Python.

(I'm a little unsure about the if that tries to handle cases where the URL's path component is the root (`/`); adjust/test if that matters to you.)

Answer (score 2):

One method is to `rev` the URL then cut the field and then `rev` again. eg:

```
echo 'http://www.test.com/abc/def/efg/file.jar ' | rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev
```

Output:

```
file.jar
```

Example 2:

```
echo 'http://www.test.com/abc/cscsc/sccsc/def/efg/file.jar ' | rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev
```

Output:

```
file.jar
```